# Embed image in an imagefilledellipse without covering text data

Tags: php, image

I was really excited to be able to fill my imagefilledellipse with a photo using this technique:

```
$bg = imagecreatefrompng("myimage.png");
imagesettile($im, $bg);
imagefilledellipse($im, $center_pt, $center_pt, $diameter - ($inner_diameter_offset * 2), $diameter - ($inner_diameter_offset * 2), IMG_COLOR_TILED);// creates the shape of my circle to be filled with png
header("content-type: image/png");
imagepng($im);
imagedestroy($im);
imagedestroy($bg);
```

The only problem?  There was a lot of data being displayed in my (formally yellow, '$yellow' ellipse).  Now all the text disappears. But 'myimage.png' doesn't seem to just be covering my text, it seems to have erased all text, even in other imagefilledellipses that have been drawn in the page.

http://flylib.com/books/en/1.265.1.225/1/
Recommends to use imagestring like so:

```
imagestring($image, 4, 20, 90, 'No worries....', $drawing_color);
```

But the 'imagestring' solution only seems to work by repeating the text 'No worries...' and I want to show all the variables that were previously displayed on top of my drawn ellipses.

Thank you for you help with this!
Amber

Answer (score 0):

Great, I found out what the problem was!  The imagepng and imagedestroy had to be removed.  Specifically the following were deleted and now it works.

```
imagepng($im);
imagedestroy($im);
imagedestroy($bg);
```